# Issue with inserting / arranging columns using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel worksheeet which has a number of columns, typically from A to AZ. I've written something in VBA which is supposed to arrange and clean this worksheet by calling other subroutines, each which perform an individual task such as formatting, deleting rows, inserting new columns and moving and renaming existing ones.

I'm very new to VBA, so a lot of what I have written is what I've managed to find on here or google. I'm not sure whether the way I have written this is the best way of performing the task.

The problem I have is that the first part one of the subs (arrangeColumns) which is supposed to insert a new column at A *somtimes* works. The other times it appears to copy the entire worksheet and duplicate it so that my columns now go from A - AZ and are duplicated again from BA - CZ.

From what what little knowledge I have I've managed to find out that when I run this sub on its own it does work, however when this sub is called from my main part it doesnt peform as it should.

Apart from the very first column not being inserted correctly the rest of the code seems to work. Any help or suggestions welcome! thanks

```
Sub ArrangeColumns()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test")

'inserts Index column at A. This is the part that seems to fail and duplicates the worksheet
ws.Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert
ws.Range("A1").Value = "Index"

'identifies last column
Dim lastColumn As Long
lastColumn = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).column

'Finds the column Timestamp: Time and moves to B, renames to Date
Dim column As Range
For Each column In ws.Range("A1:" & Split(ws.Cells(1, lastColumn).Address, "$")(1) & "1").Cells
   If column.Value = "Timestamp: Time" Then
       column.EntireColumn.Cut
       ws.Range("B1").Insert shift:=xlToRight
       ws.Range("B1").Value = "Date"
       Exit For
   End If
Next column

'inserts Time column at C
ws.Range("C1").EntireColumn.Insert
ws.Range("C1").Value = "Time"

'inserts blank column at D
ws.Range("D1").EntireColumn.Insert
ws.Range("D1").Value = "Blank"

'finds the column Body and moves to E
For Each column In ws.Range("A1:" & Split(ws.Cells(1, lastColumn).Address, "$")(1) & "1").Cells
   If column.Value = "Body" Then
       column.EntireColumn.Cut
       ws.Range("E1").Insert shift:=xlToRight
       Exit For
   End If
Next column

'find the From column and moves to F
For Each column In ws.Range("A1:" & Split(ws.Cells(1, lastColumn).Address, "$")(1) & "1").Cells
   If column.Value = "From" Then
       column.EntireColumn.Cut
       ws.Range("F1").Insert shift:=xlToRight
       ws.Range("F1").Value = "From User"
       Exit For
   End If
Next column

'inserts From Attributed column at G
ws.Range("G1").EntireColumn.Insert
ws.Range("G1").Value = "From Attributed"

'find th To column and moves to H, renames to To User
For Each column In ws.Range("A1:" & Split(ws.Cells(1, lastColumn).Address, "$")(1) & "1").Cells
   If column.Value = "To" Then
       column.EntireColumn.Cut
       ws.Range("H1").Insert shift:=xlToRight
       ws.Range("H1").Value = "To User"
       Exit For
   End If
Next column

'inserts To Attributed at I
ws.Range("I1").EntireColumn.Insert
ws.Range("I1").Value = "To Attributed"

'finds Participants column and moves to J
For Each column In ws.Range("A1:" & Split(ws.Cells(1, lastColumn).Address, "$")(1) & "1").Cells
   If column.Value = "Participants" Then
       column.EntireColumn.Cut
       ws.Range("J1").Insert shift:=xlToRight
       Exit For
   End If
Next column

'Finds Source column and moves to K
For Each column In ws.Range("A1:" & Split(ws.Cells(1, lastColumn).Address, "$")(1) & "1").Cells
   If column.Value = "Source" Then
       column.EntireColumn.Cut
       ws.Range("K1").Insert shift:=xlToRight
       Exit For
   End If
Next column

End Sub


Sub deleteFirstRow()
'deletes the first row of the worksheet

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test")

ws.Rows(1).Delete

End Sub


Sub convertToRange()
'loops throught the worksheet to find all tables and converts to range

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test")

Dim table As ListObject
For Each table In ws.ListObjects
   table.Range.Copy
   table.Unlist
Next table

End Sub


Sub clearFilter()
'removes all filters on activesheet

On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

End Sub


Sub formatting()
'if this sub is called after cleaning the columns, then the index will be blank. This uses the column titled '#' to find the lastrow

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim col As Range

Set col = Rows(1).Find("#", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, col.column).End(xlUp).Row
lastColumn = Cells(1, columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column

Dim rngAll As Range
Set rngAll = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))

Dim rngTopRow As Range
Set rngTopRow = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, lastColumn))

Dim rngSecondRowDown As Range
Set rngSecondRowDown = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))

With rngAll
   .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
   .Borders.Weight = xlThin
   .Borders.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic

   .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
   .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter

   .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
   .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin
   .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).ColorIndex = xlAutomatic

   .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
   .Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlThin
   .Borders(xlInsideVertical).ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
End With

'sets the colour, font and row size of the first row
With rngTopRow
   .Interior.Color = RGB(48, 84, 150)
   .Font.Color = vbWhite
   .Font.Bold = True
   .RowHeight = 40
End With

'sets colour, borders and row size of rows 2 to lastrow
With rngSecondRowDown
   .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
   .RowHeight = 50
End With

End Sub



Sub splitDateTime()
'if this sub is called after cleaning the columns, then the index will be blank. This uses the column titled '#' to find the lastrow
'Splits the values in column B from 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss' by space and moves 'hh:mm:ss' to column c

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim col As Range

Set col = Rows(1).Find("#", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, col.column).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow
   Cells(i, 3).Value = Mid(Cells(i, 2).Value, 12, 16)
   Cells(i, 2).Value = Left(Cells(i, 2).Value, 10)
Next i

End Sub


Sub columnWidth()

columns("a").columnWidth = 15
columns("b").columnWidth = 11
columns("c:d").columnWidth = 15
columns("e").columnWidth = 30
columns("f:i").columnWidth = 22
columns("j").columnWidth = 40

End Sub


Sub applyFilter()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test")
Dim rngAll As Range

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim col As Range

Set col = Rows(1).Find("#", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, col.column).End(xlUp).Row
lastColumn = Cells(1, columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column

Set rngAll = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
rngAll.AutoFilter

End Sub



Sub arrangeWorksheet()

Call clearFilter
Call deleteFirstRow
Call convertToRange
Call ArrangeColumns
Call formatting
Call splitDateTime
Call columnWidth
Call applyFilter

End Sub
```

Comment: Does your worksheet contain any merged cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the problem, which was in the `converToRange()` sub. I was copying the table before converting it to range, which meant when the next sub was called it was pasting it instead of inserting a new column!

Answer (score 0):

There is a bunch of repeated logic/steps in your `ArrangeColumns` which could be pushed out into a separate reusable method.

For example:

```vb
Sub arrangeWorksheet()
    Call ArrangeColumns
End Sub


Sub ArrangeColumns()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, rwHeaders As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test")
    
    Set rwHeaders = ws.Rows(1) 'headers are here
    
    MoveOrAddColumn rwHeaders, "", "Index", "A"
    MoveOrAddColumn rwHeaders, "Timestamp: Time", "Date", "B"
    MoveOrAddColumn rwHeaders, "", "Time", "C"
    MoveOrAddColumn rwHeaders, "", "Blank", "D"
    MoveOrAddColumn rwHeaders, "Body", "", "E"
    MoveOrAddColumn rwHeaders, "From", "From User", "F"
    MoveOrAddColumn rwHeaders, "", "From Attributed", "G"
    MoveOrAddColumn rwHeaders, "To", "To User", "H"
    MoveOrAddColumn rwHeaders, "", "To Attributed", "I"
    MoveOrAddColumn rwHeaders, "Participants", "", "J"
    MoveOrAddColumn rwHeaders, "Source", "", "K"
    
End Sub

'With all headers in range `rwHeaders`...
'Move a column named `existingColName` to `destColLetter` (if existingColName is supplied)
'Otherwise insert a new column at position `destColLetter`
'Moved/inserted column is given header `newColName` (if supplied)
Sub MoveOrAddColumn(rwHeaders As Range, existingColName, newColName, destColLetter)
    Dim m, colRng As Range, f As Range, cDest As Range, moving
    
    Set cDest = rwHeaders.Columns(destColLetter) 'destination if moving, or new column
    moving = Len(existingColName) > 0
    
    If moving Then 'moving an existing column?
        Set f = rwHeaders.Find(what:=existingColName, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If f Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Column header '" & existingColName & "' not found!"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            If f.column <> cDest.column Then 'check if already in the requested postion
                cDest.EntireColumn.Insert shift:=xlToRight
                Set cDest = cDest.Offset(0, -1) 're-point reference
                f.EntireColumn.Copy cDest
                f.EntireColumn.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Else
        cDest.EntireColumn.Insert shift:=xlToRight
        Set cDest = cDest.Offset(0, -1) 're-point reference
    End If
    If Len(newColName) > 0 Then cDest.Value = newColName
End Sub
```

Comment: This is great, thank you for helping with this part of the process. I've tested this arrange columns a few times and seems to be more efficient / running quicker.